# tailwind stop working after add custom color to tailwind.config.js

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

im using tailwind in my Nextjs project. i decided to add my own color set to tailwind.config.js. then when i go back to my project i saw some tailwind classes for some elements not working and some of them works like before. the codes that should be in global css are there. `@tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities;`
and global css imported in layout. it was working fine whole the time. i changed nothing but just i said earlier. maybe its worth to know that im using **experimental feature (appDir) in next.config.js.**

its now my tailwind.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

portcss file:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

also has the tailwind in package.json:  `"tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"`

i removed the color set but didnt fixed the problem. i tried `npm run dev -- --no-cache` 
but didnt helped. deleting .next  also not worked. even moved the folder but the problem exist. then i deleted all tailwind config files and reinstall them and not everything just messed up. there is no more tailwind classes working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have You tried adding and

```
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"
  ]
```

Comment: i had "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", but somehow  "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}" was missing. now its all fixed.thank you so much.

Comment: Not a biggie, always a pleasure